# Naming Convention in tableView functions

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

So I am just getting into the whole tableView thing but I came across a curious observations and have a question:

Why is it that overriding this function in my `UITableViewController` class

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
```

has a descriptive name but the number of rows in the section is determined this way

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

I find the former much more logical and wonder why it is not used consequently for other tableView parameters.

**Why are different versions of the function tableView called for most tableView properties, instead of different functions with descriptive names?**

I am sure there is a very good reason and would be thankful if someone wiser than me could shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254875/why-do-all-methods-have-the-same-name-in-delegate

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172041/override-function and https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-does-override-mean

Comment: But when compatibility with Objective-C is the reason, why is `numberOfSections` exempt from this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do all methods have the same name in delegate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254875/why-do-all-methods-have-the-same-name-in-delegate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to put it frankly: **Compatibility with Objective-C seems to be the reason for this inconsistency.**